# Calling 2 API's in the same screen

Tags: api, react-native, axios

In my react native app i want to make 2 API calls in the same screen and they both have IDs in them, but when i put the second call none of the calls work, here is the code:

```
 async componentDidMount(){
    axios.get('http://reduxblog.herokuapp.com/api/posts/{{ID}}')
     .then((response) =>  { this.setState({ data: response.data})});
  }

  async componentDidMount(){
    axios.get('http://reduxblog.herokuapp.com/api/comments={{ID}}')
     .then((response) =>  { this.setState({ data: response.data})});
  }
```

Comment: You're redefining `componentDidMount`. You need to put both GET requests in the same function block.

Comment: You're redefining `componentDidMount`. You need to put both GET requests in the same function block.

Answer (score 1):

```
componentDidMount() {
  const { id } = this.props; // I am not sure how you get ID
  this.loadData(id);
}

loadData = async (id) => {
  const posts = await axios.get(`http://reduxblog.herokuapp.com/api/posts/${id}`);
  const comments = await axios.get(`http://reduxblog.herokuapp.com/api/comments/${id}`);
  this.setState({
    posts,
    comments
  });
}
```

Comment: it's returning "Unhandled promise rejection", the state for the posts should have the response from the first call, and the state for the comments should have the response from the second call